# Abstract Lie algebra

Tags: lie-algebras

For six dimensional Lie algebra with non-zero Lie brackets defined as follow: $[e_{1}, e_{3}] = -e_{1}, [e_{1}, e_{6}] = -e_{2}, [e_{2}, e_{3}] = -e_{2}, [e_{2}, e_{4}] = e_{1}, [e_{2}, e_{5}] = e_{2}, [e_{4}, e_{5}] = -e_{4}, [e_{4}, e_{6}] = -2*e_{5}-e_{3}, [e_{5}, e_{6}] = -e_{6}$.
What would be quotient algebra $\frac{\text{Nor}\left(w_{1}\right)}{w_{1}}$ for $w_{1}=a*e_{3}+e_{5}$ ?
Where 'a' is arbitrary constant $\neq 0, 1$ .
The expected answer is $\{e_{3}\}$

Comment: What are all the $a$'s?

Comment: What does that mean? Please try to write this as you would in math terms, rather than Maple notation.

Comment: The question is fully edited in simpler version.

Comment: What is the normalizer of an element? You mean the normalizer of the subalgebra generated by that element? And similarly, you you mean to take the quotient by the subalgebra generated by the element, rather than just the element?

Comment: If $[w_{1}, w_{2}]= \lambda*w_{1}$ then we say $w_{2}\in \text{Nor}\left(w_{1}\right)$, where $\lambda$ being arbitrary constant.

Comment: I mean quotient algebra of Normalizer.

Comment: Right, so that is the normalizer of the subalgebra generated by the element.

Comment: The normalizer can be straightforwardly computed using Maple package Lie Algebra but problem is with its quotient algebra.

Comment: I am not sure how the expected answer could be some element from the Lie algebra itself, as the quotient will not be a subset of this. Do you mean you expect that element to map to a generator of the quotient under the natural projection?

Comment: Please see research article [http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/jmp/33/10/10.1063/1.529907] at page 3592, in first column and 4th 2-dimensional sub-algebra for such construction.

Comment: It says file not found.

Comment: "Group‐invariant solutions and optimal systems for multidimensional
hydrodynamics", Journal of Mathematical Physics.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really feel like looking through a paper on mathematical physics to try to understand what you are asking.

Comment: This paper concerns with classification of six dimensional Lie algebra. Anyway, thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Lie Algebra package of Maple for computing normalizer. Use following command:

> NormalizerSubalgebra(S)

Here S is subset of Lie algebra whose normalizer is required.